# AJAX dynamic Dependent Select Box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

**What i need?**

I need to create an input form that must be fille up with dynamic dropdown list as per below screenshot.

[image: Example]

**What is my actual script??**

Actually is divided in some files, i'll ignore the database connection and the functions file.

*assign.php*

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['log'])){
include ('connection.php');
include ('functions.php');
//Variables que vienen desde el boton de ASSIGN 
    $szDescription = $_POST['szDescription'];
    $szRequestor = $_POST['szRequestor'];
    $szRecived = $_POST['szRecived'];
    $szCID = $_POST['szCID'];
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, 
initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="..\css\bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="..\css\style.css">

        <script type="text/javascript">
        // Select Category function
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#szTeam').on('change',function(){
                var team_selected = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'getcategory.php',
                    data:'teamselected='+team_selected,
                    success:function(html){
                        $('#optionCategory').html(html);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        // FIN TEAM Select
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid"><div class="container">
            <p class="bg-Success">You are about to assign this ticket:</p>
            <p><b>Subject:</b><i> <?php echo $szDescription ?></i></p>
            <p><b>From:</b><i> <?php echo $szRequestor ?></i></p>
            <p><b>Recived:</b><i> <?php echo $szRecived ?></i></p>
            <form action="" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="szTeam">Team</label>
                    <select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="szTeam" id="szTeam">
                    <option>Select Team</option>
                        <?php
                        foreach($_SESSION['userteam'] as $userteamsArray){
                            echo "<option>".$userteamsArray."</option>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="optionCategory">Category</label>
                    <select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="optionCategory" id="optionCategory" >
                    <option></option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="SubmitButton">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

*getcategory.php*

```
<?php

include ('connection.php');

$team = $_POST['teamselected'];

$query = "SELECT szActivitySubCategory FROM Subcategories WHERE szTeam = '$team'";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);
if(!$result){
    echo "<center>Error detected:Query <b>".$query."</b> did not work. 
   <br>Please contact the administrator</center><br>".sqlsrv_errors($query);
}
$ouput = "<option value=\"\">Select Category</option>";
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $selected = $row['szActivitySubCategory'];
    $ouput = $ouput."<option value='$selected'> $selected </option>";
}

echo $ouput;

?>
```

**What is happening??**

The code is not working as expected. I tested the getcategory.php file using a default team and works properly.. it return an option list with the results of the query.

Also, the rest of the code seems to be correct.
The jquery is suppose to insert the ouput from getcategory.php in the id ('#optioncategory')  but it doesn't.

**I've already read:**

http://www.lisenme.com/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using-jquery-ajax-php/

But it does not help me at all because my code is simillar and have the same structure.

Any suggestion to fix it??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're neither sanitizing the input from the query nor are you using a prepared statement, both of which can lead to disaster. I would be able to help you, but my solution would utilize PDO. So before I answer, would a PDO example be acceptable?

Comment: Yep, im using PDO in all the code.

Comment: I discover the error! jquery script was not added!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The code were incomplete. It was a missing script on the header:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Regards,